# Visual Studio Code Does Not Accept Code Changes on Mac OS X

Tags: asp.net, macos

I created a plain ASP.NET 5 (vNext) app from Visual Studio 2015 RC in Windows. I then checked my code into GitHub and pulled it down onto my Mac OS X environment. I have Visual Studio Code installed on it.

I can successfully run the ASP.NET 5 app by running `dnx . kestrel` from the terminal window in Mac OS X. However, if I change any of the HTML, JavaScript, or anything, I cannot see the change take effect. Instead, I have to kill the process that contains `dnx`. Then I have to run `dnx . kestrel` again.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug that's a work in progress?

Thank you!